# Deletion of Directory in linux ( can't even ls that directory)

Tags: linux, shell, cron, sh, superuser

I have a directory called `pics_temp` which is soooo big, i can't even `ls` that directory and it has millions of files. I would like to delete that file. I can't use `rm` or `rmdir` and `xargs rm -rf`, because it will take much much longer time and the program will terminate by itself, that large is that directory... Is there any way that can i delete that directory ?

Can I write shell script and put it in cron job or is there any other way to delete contents in that directory ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that it is off-topic here and you should post it on SuperUser

Comment: Why do you believe the "program will terminate by itself"? What time-limit constraint system is imposing this limitation? And even if it does terminate early it will have made some progress and further runs should make more progress until eventually it finishes

Comment: I need that folder, i want to delete contents in that folder. If i want to delete so big giant directory which one works faster. Please give me your valuable advice

Comment: You can execute that in background. It will take time, but it will not affect your foreground process.

Answer (score 1):

Try `find`.

```
find pics_temp -mindepth 1 -print -delete
```

`find` invoked like this will not try to buffer large amounts of filenames and will not be restricted by the maximum length of an argument list or the long time it can take to fork a process millions of times. `-mindepth 1` will cause it to delete everything inside `pics_temp` but not the directory itself.

It also doesn't rely on `printf %s\\n *` or `ls` or other such commands, which all share the drawback of requiring all files to be known before they start generating output.

The command given above has `-print`, which will print files before it deletes them. This can be useful to tell you that something is actually happening, but it will slow down the operation. When you are confident that it is working, you might want to remove the `-print` so that the command runs faster.

Comment: This also take the time to delete.

Comment: No matter how you do it, it's going to take a long time to delete that many files.